# What's the easiest way to use the output paths from a git command in a subsequent git command?

Tags: linux, git, bash, shell, command-line

I far too frequently use the mouse to do things like this:

```
/home/me-$ git log --name-status -1  
commit a10e63af1f4b1b2c28055fed55d4f2bb3225a541
Author: Me <me@me.com>
Date:   Tue Aug 18 13:04:04 2015 -0400

    XYZ-376 make ctors public

M       x/y/z/Class1.java
M       x/y/z/Class2.java

/home/me-$ git checkout -- x/y/z/Class2.java  # <-- copy/paste with the mouse
```

I know that some git commands accept wildcards, and this mitigates this problem somewhat, but I'm wondering if there is a way do specifically reference pathspecs, etc. from previous commands.

How can I run commands like this without using the mouse, and without retyping long paths by hand?

Comment: You can use shell history using `ctrl+r`.

Comment: How are you choosing which part of the previous output you want to use?

Comment: @VishnuAtrai I'm interested in the output, not the command itself.

Comment: @EricRenouf edited for clarification; in general, I'm talking about pathspecs, but the same question could apply to things like branch names, remotes, etc.

Comment: @jordanpg Could you please clarify whether you'd like to run git checkout on all the paths listed in the output of `git log --name-status -1`?

Comment: @Jubobs I'm asking the more general question:  given a pathspec in the output of a git command, how can I easily reference it in a subsequent command without retyping/copy-pasting-with-mouse?  So I would like to know how to reference 0, 1, and N of the output paths.

Comment: How would you specify which of the paths to "reference"?

Comment: @Jubobs I don't know; that's what I'm asking.  `git stash` uses a notation like `{N}` to refer to the stack of stashes.  Revision syntax has all kinds of exotic notation.  git plumbing commands, too.

Comment: @jordanpg It almost sounds like you'd like to click on the path of interest. Perhaps you should use a GUI.

Comment: @Jubobs No, as is implied (I thought), the point is to improve efficiency on CLI.  In fact, I am currently clicking on the paths, in order to copy them, and then again clicking to paste.  That's 2 clicks too many for me.

Comment: @jordanpg If you call a function that returns *just* a path of interest (or a stream of them), you could pass that to the next function. But how do you intend to extract the paths from the output of a porcelain command such as `git log`? You'd have to, somehow, parse that output. I think you're using the wrong tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I typically use a subshell (`$(<command in subshell here...>)`) for this.

For example, sometimes I had many files deleted and I had to `git rm` every one of them.

There's the command `git ls-files --deleted` that returns the names of all the missing files. I can combine it with `git rm` like this:

```
git rm $(git ls-files --deleted)
```

This is somewhat a bad example, because (as I discovered later), this operation can be achieved much easier with `git add --all`. But I think it illustrates the point.

---

In your case, if you wanted to checkout all files that have been changed in the previous commit, it would be hard to parse the output of `git log --name-status`, because it contains additional information, but you could use something like `git diff HEAD^ --name-only` instead.

So:

```
git checkout $(git diff HEAD^ --name-only)
```

will do it in your example.

One nice thing that I noticed using the `$(...)` syntax is that it works both in Bash *and* in PowerShell.

Comment: I think this method could work with a small utility that does something like this:  `git diff --name-only | cat -n; getFileNumber.sh 2` where the new command does something like `!! | cat -n | grep $linenum | awk '{print $2}'`.

Comment: The problem I'm running into here is `fatal: Unable to create '../.git/index.lock': File exists.`, due to running git in a command substitution block inside another git command.  I wonder if there's a way to tell git to ignore the lockfile for read only commands?

Comment: I don't know if there is. But are you sure it's worth going through such pain to avoid two clicks?

Comment: Here's another idea: if you only want one file, but it has a very long path, you can use the glob syntax to avoid typing in paths: `git checkout -- **Class2.java`. Note that this will check out any files called `Class2.java`  in the repo. But I still find the `-- **` useful and use it a lot.

Comment: Does running `eval export ${!GIT_*}` before running your own command help that?  I give it maybe a half shot of working, give it a whirl.

Comment: @w0lf I didn't know about that! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This'd be the kind of thing you run a shell under emacs for, run all your shells in it and have a command to walk back through the buffer looking for patterns in the output.

For retrieving output from a previous command that you didn't capture inside the shell session, you're going to have to get it from your terminal emulator's buffers somehow. [The xterm family has a configurable "copy the whole scrollback buffer" thingy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109509/how-to-search-xterm-console-history), then `xclip -o` will print the selection and you can pipe it through an extraction filter.

But it's either capture the output within the session or scrape it from the output buffers afterwards, that's everywhere the data's ever been.

Answer (score 0):

On OS X, "Mouseless Copy" supported by iTerm2 (and probably some other terminal emulators) is a workable solution: https://www.iterm2.com/features.html

- search for some portion of the string (⌘F)
- expand selection right (tab) or left (shift-tab)
- paste selection with (option-enter) or copy/paste in the usual way